# R highcharter waterfall chart x-axis and color problems

Tags: r, r-highcharter

```
library(highcharter)
df = data.frame(Name = c("Total","A","B","C","D"),
                Value = c(10,5,9,-1,-3))
df
   Name Value
1 Total    10
2     A     5
3     B     9
4     C    -2
5     D    -3

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "waterfall") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$Name) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df[1,2]) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = df[-1,2])
```

I am trying to create a waterfall chart with the codes above and encountered two problems:

1. `A` somehow got grouped together with `Total` although it showed as `Series 2`. As a result, `Value` and `Name` were mismatching on the chart;
2. I have tried the following codes to set the green color for positive values and red for negative ones. It works for `Total` but not others.

```
library(dplyr)
df2= df %>%
  mutate(color = ifelse(df$Value>=0,"green",ifelse(df$Value<0,"red",NA)))
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "waterfall") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = df2$Name) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df2[1,2], color = df2[1,3]) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = df2[-1,2], colors = df2[-1,3])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to the first question, as @jbkunst pointed out [here](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/153), is that every value is 0-index in the first category when adding them as separate series. I am not sure if it's possible to specify the index for the second index. I have tried adding `[1]` but did not work.

In terms of the second question, the key is to include the argument `isSum`. However, the problem is the calculation only goes from left to right. Here is what I mean: if `isSum = c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)`, then `D` will become `23`, which is the sum of the previous four values. Now if `isSum = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)`, then `Total` will become `0` because there is no number before it.

That being said, the working solution I found was moving the `Total` to the end:

```
df2 = data.frame(Name = c("A","B","C","D","Total"),
                Value = c(5,9,-1,-3,10))
a = c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)
df2= df2 %>%
  mutate(color = ifelse(df2$Value>=0,"green",ifelse(df2$Value<0,"red",NA)))
highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_add_series(data = df2, type = "waterfall", hcaes(x = Name, y= Value, isSum = a, color = df2$color))
```